# Timeout in new requests but existing connections remain

Tags: windows, internet, ping, timeout

I often encounter some weird timeouts where I get a timeout when searching in the web for example. However an existing connection e.g. on a Discord voice chat or on a game server persists without any problems. But if I left the game server and tried to join again, it won't work until the whole timeout is over (when the web is also working again).

Does anybody know what this might be?

Comment: Sounds like a DNS issue. A DNS issue would impact new connections because the ip address cannot be resolved, but existing connections that already have been resolved will continue to work. It may also be a router that is in crashed state, and it can be a combination. So try rebooting the router.

Comment: When you next get the issue, it might be worth running the following in an admin Powershell prompt: `Get-NetTCPConnection  | group State | select count, name` just to see the count of each of the TCP connection states.

Comment: see if it's helpful to you: https://kinsta.com/blog/err_connection_timed_out/

Comment: It's not a DNS issue but a network issue. In most of the cases it's MTU of the router which leads to the loss of the packets. Check with your ISP which MTU to set. Also check https://superuser.com/questions/386708/cant-access-some-websites-possible-mtu-issue-on-the-router

Comment: @HelpingHand this is the output: 
``122 Bound | 38 Listen | 137 Established | 8 SynSent | 2 LastAck | 4 FinWait1 | 1 TimeWait | 2 FinWait2 | 11 CloseWait``